# How do you fix an attribute error when using "fillpdfs.write_fillable_pdf"?

Tags: python, pdf, pdfrw

I am trying to fill out the rest of a partially filled out pdf form, however, when I try to update some of the values in the form using "fillpdfs", I receive a Attribute Error stating: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'. Any help in understanding this issue would be fantastic! I have attached a full screen shot of the error.
[image: Screenshot of full error message]

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the modules however this did not work. I have also tried changing the names of the pdf files themselves.

Comment: Don't make us squint to read code in an image.  Please post all code and errors as plain text.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few possible causes for this error:

The write_fillable_pdf function might not be defined. Make sure that you have correctly imported the fillpdf library and that you are using the correct function name.

The write_fillable_pdf function might be expecting certain arguments, and you are not providing them. Make sure that you are passing the correct number and type of arguments to the function.

The write_fillable_pdf function might be trying to access an attribute or property that does not exist. Make sure that you are providing the correct data to the function and that the data you are using has the required attributes.

To troubleshoot this error further, you can try the following:

Check the documentation for the fillpdf library to make sure you are using the correct function name and arguments.

Check the stack trace of the error to see which line of code is causing the issue. This can help you identify which part of your code is causing the problem.

Print out the values of the arguments that you are passing to the write_fillable_pdf function to make sure they are correct.

Add some debug statements to your code to print out the value of any attributes that the write_fillable_pdf function is trying to access.

Comment: import fillpdf

# Open the fillable PDF form
with open('form.pdf', 'rb') as f:
  form = f.read()

# Define the data to be written to the form
data = {
  'field_name_1': 'Value 1',
  'field_name_2': 'Value 2'
}

# Write the data to the form and save the resulting PDF
output_pdf = fillpdf.write_fillable_pdf(form, data)
with open('filled_form.pdf', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(output_pdf)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).